# Node MongoDB RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, recursion, stack

I'm performing a `bulk upsert` using an `orderedBulkOperation`.

This is for a very large list of documents. It's ran fine for about a year on the cloud.

In the past couple weeks though, I've gotten `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Looks like Node's call stack size has been exceeded.

```
 /var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:691
 throw error;
 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
 at ServerSessionPool.acquire (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sessions.js:623:12)
 at ClientSession.get serverSession [as serverSession] (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sessions.js:113:47)
 at /var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sessions.js:148:19
 at maybePromise (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:685:3)
 at ClientSession.endSession (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sessions.js:130:12)
 at Cursor._endSession (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:392:15)
 at done (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:448:16)
 at /var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:536:11
 at /var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:688:9
 at /var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:82:7
 at maybePromise (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:685:3)
 at executeOperation (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:34:10)
 at Cursor._initializeCursor (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:534:7)
 at Cursor._initializeCursor (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:186:11)
 at Object.callback (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:439:14)
 at processWaitQueue (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:1049:21)
 at NativeTopology.selectServer (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:449:5)
 at executeWithServerSelection (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:131:12)
 at /var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:70:9
 at maybePromise (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:685:3)
 at executeOperation (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:34:10)
 at Cursor._initializeCursor (/var/app/current/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:534:7)
```

is the full stack trace. The last couple times had very similar trace. Looks like stack size has exceeded due to recursive call and there being no base of recursion.

I'm unable to reproduce this issue locally, and it's hard deduce what exactly is breaking this.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you have the right diagnosis.  I don't know how these tools use recursion, but it seems as though there is something a little off about it.  I would not expect a bulk update to be deeply recursive.  If you can't simply split the update into smaller chunks, then it's probably a slog through that call-stack to see what's going on.

Comment: mm...tough bc I cannot reproduce and it seems to only be happening on Prod (not even staging). Not finding anything on Mongo Logs (makes sense bc it's the client that's crashing). My node mongo driver did update from 3.1.1 to 3.9. There's a lot in changelogs though.

Might be worth it to just replace the now deprecated `remove` to `delete` and see it that solves it. Quicker than refactoring whole thing and applying chunking

Comment: Sporadic problems are the worst.  I would definitely make the changes suggested by the changelogs.  Or if you have A/B environments, try rolling one back to an earlier version, and if at all possible, mirror the calls so that they're running the same input.  But quite often, that's simply not possible, and again, it's a slog through the code.  Sorry not to have better news.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback and insights. I'm seeing now that the Mongo updates opt in to set `useUnifiedTopology` to true. Some brief research on this option yields lots of terms that are similar to stack trace above. But - I don't want to just set this to false and hope for best haha